# Attempting to DIY solder repair a broken USB Flash Drive

Tags: usb, repair

[image]

I plan to solder the wiring from a cable with the USB end onto my USB flash drive.

I'm just not sure where to solder the wires…

This PCB is different from the DIY I've seen online.

Comment: Your picture shows wrong side of the board. Please show the other side, where the actual connections should go.

Answer (score 1):

From your other picture, the actual connector's pads are completely ripped off PCB. So there is nothing to solder to. However, the shown side indicates that the repair can be done. Here are the new soldering points:

[image]

While VBUS and ground can be soldered to the indicated spots easily, the D+/D- have to be soldered to tiny traces marked as "D+ D-". This is a job for a highly qualified technician in modern PCB repair. You will need a stereo microscope 20X-30X, finest soldering tip (0.1mm) and intermediate AWG38-AWG40 wire to make the connection. This is not a first-time DIY soldering job, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From your picture:

[image]

Note those metal tabs soldered into the right end of the PCB. Those were originally part of the shell of the Type A USB connector. The connector was mounted from the other side of the PCB. So turn it over to see where the four contacts of the USB connector were attached. Your cable wires will need to go to those four places.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1545453/attempting-to-diy-a-broken-usb-flash-drive-continued