# Attempting to DIY a broken USB Flash Drive (continued)

Tags: usb, repair

[image: This is an iPhone USB Lightning cable with its internal wiring revealed. From left to right, the color are yellow, green, red, gray and I'm **assuming** the others are strips of a layer of casing]

I posted yesterday about attempting a DIY to fix a snapped off USB Flash Drive.

So far, I've identified where I will solder the wires (thank you Micheal) on the PCB. I would just like clarification on what my wires are because none of my wires are black or white.

On top of that, the yellow leftmost wire is thinner than the rest. Why is that?

I'm thinking

- red is red: +5V
- green is green: Data +
- yellow is white: Data - ?
- gray is black: GND ?

Image description: This is an iPhone USB Lightning cable with its internal wiring revealed. From left to right, the color are yellow, green, red, gray and I'm **assuming** the others are strips of a layer of casing.

Comment: you could always check continuity of the wires to the internl pin of the USB connector of the cable. This always works for me but it's often a chore to get a DMM probe touching those pins on the inside. This image might help out with what should be what https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/USB.svg/1200px-USB.svg.png (source: wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

It could be damaging to guess at the wires and I guess that this is the reason for why you have posted this question here.

There are several ways to work out which wires in the cable correspond to what function. Probably the best is to reference figures like the following from online and use an ohm meter to measure continuity from each wire end back to the contacts on the connector.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://posaok.com/wordpress/2017/11/30/what-trouble-do-we-meet-with-apple-lightning-type-c-for-audio-pop/)*</sup>

There is also a plethora of various sorts of information regarding Lightning connectors and cables. Try a search.